# Django Rest Framework 'list' object has no attribute values

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have the code and error stacktrace below.

I am trying to access `localhost:8000/fundamentals/` but I get the error `'list' object has no attribute 'values'`

error

```
web_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
web_1  |     response = get_response(request)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 202, in _get_response
web_1  |     response = response.render()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
web_1  |     self.content = self.rendered_content
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py", line 70, in rendered_content
web_1  |     ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 724, in render
web_1  |     context = self.get_context(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 655, in get_context
web_1  |     raw_data_post_form = self.get_raw_data_form(data, view, 'POST', request)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py", line 563, in get_raw_data_form
web_1  |     data = serializer.data.copy()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 562, in data
web_1  |     ret = super().data
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 264, in data
web_1  |     self._data = self.get_initial()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 412, in get_initial
web_1  |     for field in self.fields.values()
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 413, in <listcomp>
web_1  |     if not field.read_only
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 412, in get_initial
web_1  |     for field in self.fields.values()
web_1  | AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
web_1  | [05/Sep/2020 11:42:59] "GET /fundamentals/ HTTP/1.1" 500 99118
```

models/fundamentals.py

```
  7 class Fundamentals(models.Model):
  8     balance_sheet = models.ForeignKey(BalanceSheet, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  9     ticker = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 10     slug = models.SlugField(default="", editable=False)
 11
 12     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
 13         value = self.ticker
 14         self.slug = slugify(value, allow_unicode=True)
 15         super().save(*args, **kwargs)
 16
 17     def __str__(self):
 18         return {f"{self.ticker} fundamentals"}
 19
 20     class Meta:
 21         verbose_name = "fundamentals"
 22         verbose_name_plural = "fundamentals"
```

views.py

```
 13 class FundamentalsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
 14     queryset = Fundamentals.objects.all()
 15     serializer_class = FundamentalsSerializer
 16     # lookup_url_kwarg = "ticker"
 17     # lookup_field = "ticker__iexact"
 18
 19     def get_balance_sheets(self, requests, *args, **kwargs):
 20         bs_qs = BalanceSheet.objects.filter(ticker=self.get_object())
 21         serializer = BalanceSheetSerializer(bs_qs)
 22         return Response(serializer.data)
```

serializers.py

```
307 class BalanceSheetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
308     assets = AssetsSerializer()
309     liab_and_stock_equity = LiabAndStockEquitySerializer()
310
311     fields = [
312         "ticker",
313         "periodicity",
314         "assets",
315         "liab_and_stock_equity",
316         "end_date",
317         "start_date",
318     ]

321 class FundamentalsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
322     balance_sheet = BalanceSheetSerializer()
323
324     class Meta:
325         model = Fundamentals
326         fields = ["balance_sheet"]
```

urls.py

```
   17 router = DefaultRouter()
   18 router.register(r"fundamentals", views.FundamentalsViewSet)
   19 urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The issue here is with the `BalanceSheetSerializer`. The `fields` must be defined within class `Meta` instead of defining it as class variable.

```
class BalanceSheetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        fields = [your_fields]
```